# @davidjbradshaw's iframe resizernot working properly in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, mobile, iframe-resizer

I'm using [@davidjbradshaw's brilliant iframe resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) in an [iframe test page here](http://perfectspace.com/iframetest.htm).  When I load the page in a desktop browser (tested Chrome, Safari, and Firefox), even when I keep the width of the screen small, it loads and resizes just fine, so I would think mobile devices would respond the same. But they don't.

When I view the page in an iPhone, the width is not modified to fit properly. So, it extends the iframe horizontally.

The strange thing is that if I go to [@davidjbradshaw's example page](http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/example/) on my iPhone, they seem to work perfectly fine and do what they should be doing - resizing the width. That said, his examples are not as complex, considering I'm using bootstrap, etc.  But, I'm also not getting any JS errors at all in my code.

Additionally, going to [the source of the iframe directly](https://pingbid.net/iframes/view/api_key:2c3463251b1afabc7b71a8c73084e7e5/gid:38) on an iPhone, it loads properly, resized width and everything (because it's using twitter bootstrap 2.3.1).

Yes, I have tested by removing the head.js piece, putting `iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js` script loaded at the bottom before the `</body>` tag, and in the head.  None of those seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the ViewPort size on mobile?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My ViewPort size is set to device-width on both the page in the iframe and the page hosting the iframe.